# unidentified error while trying recursive methode

Tags: java

sorry if my question seems stupid, i'm just a newbee trying to learn java. In this code im just trying to calculate logarithm of 2 with recursive methode. But somehow eclipse tells me there are problems (the strong letters are the one which are red underlined, i tried to make those letter strong but only stars showed up instead).

Thanks and sorry for my English here. :D

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class rekursivloga {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String einlesenzahl = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bitte eine Zahl eingeben!");
    int zahl = Integer.parseInt(einlesenzahl);
    int ergebnis = logrekursiv(zahl);

    private int logrekursiv(int zahl) {
        if (zahl == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (zahl <1 ) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (zahl >1) 
            return 1 + logrekursiv (zahl/2);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: And it also tells you a specific error message in the Marker view or when you hover.

Comment: *Please* remove the stars.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a method inside another method. Move `logrekursiv` into the body of the class (and make it `static`, since there's nothing state-based in it).

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a method (`logrekursiv`) inside another method (the `main` method). This is illegal, you should move the method oustide of the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String einlesenzahl = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bitte eine Zahl eingeben!");
    int zahl = Integer.parseInt(einlesenzahl);
    int ergebnis = logrekursiv(zahl);

}

private static int logrekursiv(int zahl) {
    if (zahl == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (zahl <1 ) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + logrekursiv (zahl/2);
   }
}
```

In addition, I replaced the last if-statement with an else statement, since it does exactly the same and makes the compiler sure that a value will eventually be returned.

Make sure that you read some Java tutorials, as it seems that you have yet to learn the language properly.